# IO Error python PIL image preprocessing script

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ioerror, imdb

I am following this tutorial and specifically going through the "generate own data" section:

https://github.com/surfertas/deep_learning/tree/master/projects/imdbwiki-challenge

https://github.com/surfertas/deep_learning/blob/master/projects/imdbwiki-challenge/imdb_preprocess.py
and i am facing this issue running the imdb_preprocess.py script;

```
    Dictionary created...
Converting 1000 samples. (0=all samples)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imdb_preprocess.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "imdb_preprocess.py", line 131, in main
    create_and_dump(imdb_dict, args.partial)
  File "imdb_preprocess.py", line 106, in create_and_dump
    for img_path in imgs
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 156, in imread
    im = Image.open(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2477, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/path/48/10000548_1925-04-04_1964.jpg'
```

Now i manually checked folder 48 and checked that the image is complaining about is indeed there.

Any hints on where the fault is?

*path was replaced*

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @kpie ubuntu 16.04, but that doesn't matter(?) cause i am running it on a remote cluster with a high end gpu